# Компиляция zopfli (gcc vc msvc)

Tags: visual-c++, gcc

Скомпилировал проект [zopfli](https://github.com/google/zopfli) с помощью msvc и gcc.

Параметры msvc:

```
CFLAGS = /W2 /O2 /Ox /Ot /Ob2 /Gw /Gy /GL /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast /MT
CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) /TP /EHsc
```

Параметры gcc:

```
CFLAGS = -W -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic -lm -O3 -Wno-unused-function
CXXFLAGS = -W -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic -O3
```

Тест производительности:

```
$ time /c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/zopfli-gcc.exe --i10 /c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/enwik8

real    4m11.807s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time /c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/zopfli-vc.exe --i10 /c/Users/Lorents/Desktop/enwik8

real    4m55.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Подскажите, почему такая большая разница в производительности?

Answer (score 1):

Разные компиляторы

1. Используют разные оптимизации. Самый-самый оптимизированный код генерирует intel C compiler. Дополнительно обращаю внимание на то, что некорректно сравнивать разные уровни оптимизаций у разных компиляторов.
2. Используют разные библиотеки языка с/с++.

Не говоря уже о том, что разный размер кода, выравнивание переменных тоже даёт свой эффект в кумулятивной картине

Чтобы посмотреть, что происходит, рекомендую сделать одну из двух вещей: или сгенерировать ассемблерные листинги, или декомпилировать полученный машинный код. И сравнить результат для обоих компиляторов

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как увеличить производительность у варианта MSVC?

Comment: профилировать, профилировать и переписывать то, что будет кушать процессор. Но можно попробовать просто пересобрать с помощью mingw